# CFIMAP Reading emails from all folders

Tags: coldfusion, imap, coldfusion-9

I am using CFIMAP to download email attachments daily. Despite what I have tried so far the script is reading emails from all of my folders instead from only the inbox. Anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
    <cfimap 
        server = "mail.example.com" 
        username = "user@sexample.com" 
        action="open" 
        secure="yes" 
        password = "pass" 
        connection = "mail.example.com" >

      <cfimap   
        action="GetAll" 
        folder="Inbox"  
        name="test"
        attachmentpath="e:\testfolder" 
        GenerateUniqueFilenames="yes"
        connection="mail.example.com" >

    <cfimap 
        action="MoveMail" 
        newfolder="processedEmails" 
        stoponerror="true" 
        connection="mail.example.com">

   <cfimap action="close" connection = "mail.example.com">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try the following code..

```
<cfimap action="open" connection="Conn" server="serverurl" username="useremail"      password="passwrd" secure="yes" port="">
<cfimap action="getall" connection="Conn" name="getAttachments" folder="Inbox" attachmentpath="#GetTempDirectory()#" >

<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getMailAttachments">
    select * 
  from getAttachments 
  where seen=<cfqueryparam value="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
   and ATTACHMENTS is not null
</cfquery>
<cfloop query="getMailAttachments">
   <cfimap action="MarkRead" connection = "Conn" uid="#getMailAttachments.UID#">
   <cfimap action="movemail" connection = "Conn"  newfolder="Read mails" uid="#getMailAttachments.UID#">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: is "seen" an actual variable for attachments? Can you send me a link where you found this because I did not see it in Adobe's documentation.

Comment: "seen" is a column name when we display the result for 'getAttachments'. please try to dump the result getAttachments. you can refer http://shemy-coldfusion.blogspot.in/2012/12/coldfusion-code-to-get-mail-attachments.html